# sql - merge two tables upon value of colum

Tags: java, sql

I have two tables one with a list of cars and one list with values (of the cars) that changed over the course of time. Now I'm looking for a SQL or Java way to merge the two tables.

[image: the car table and the changed_value table]

the backend is MS-SQL. The car-table is huge and iterating and merging collections in Java requires a lot of processing power. The easiest way to merge would be in SQL but I couldn't figure out a way.

The result should be a table similar to the first one but with all the changes that are stored in the second table. (car_ref in second table references to id in first table)

The tricky part is that the column to be changed in the first table is written down in the second table (changed_value represents the column)
I somehow need a way to perform an "UPDATE SET (changed_value) TO newValue WHERE car_ref=cars.id" but all in one step

Comment: I am assuming car_ref = the ID in the car table?

Comment: What do you mean by merge the two tables? Create a new table with all of these values? Why would you do that? Or do you just mean join them to perform a query?

Comment: Show us the expected result too.

Comment: It's not a merge. The second table is a change log that you want to apply to the first table.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt , you got it! Both tables should not be changed. The result should be the first table with all the changes from the second table!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are joins -

```
SELECT * FROM cars JOIN parts ON (cars.id = parts.car_ref)
```

More information: http://www.sql-join.com/

Comment: but this doesn't replace the values, it just adds more rows

Answer (score 0):

you can used this solution for merge two table using **JOIN**

```
SELECT c.*,cv.* FROM cars as c
JOIN cars_value as cv on c.id = cv.car_ref
```

New solution :-

```
 SELECT c.*,cv.* FROM cars as c
    JOIN cars_value as cv on c.id = cv.car_ref
WHERE  cv.change_value IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.